# Rewrite Rails collection_select into Reactjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, select, collections

I'm starting to transition some of my rails forms to react, but the `collection_select` has got me stumped so far. In rails, I do the below which lets me select a given `name` from a `countries` model:

```
form.collection_select(:countries, Country.all, :id, :name, prompt: true)
```

But I can't work out how to write this in my jsx React component pulling the values from the `name` field in the `Country` model:

```
<label htmlFor="country">Country</label>
<select id="country[id]" className="form-control" name="country[name]">
    <option value="country[name]"></option>

</select>
```

Should I be adding any value to the option tag?

Comment: What do you mean by "translate this" ?

Comment: ok maybe translate isn't the right word.  I'm just trying to work out how I would write a collection_select tag in my react jsx component.

Comment: and yes, you should have values in your option tags. You should have an option tag for each Country - with the value being the Country's id ie something like: `<option value="1">Australia</option><option value="2">France</option>` etc

Comment: But are you trying to figure out what the html will look like once it's generated (so that it correctly gets sent to rails)? or are you trying to ask us to write your jsx for you to generate the above html? ;) What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can write the select in html in the jsx.  But I need it to be pulling values from my data model.  The code pasted above is one variation I've tried.

Comment: So what do you use to get the data values from rails? Do you have an ajax call that fetches the list of countries from Rails' `countries_controller#index` action?